# clientX, screenX and pageX all return -1 in IE when above the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm attempting to modify an exit intent popup to only show when the user goes to address bar and not to the back button on the side. the following code works fine in chrome and firefox:

```js
function leaveFromTop(e){
                                               
    eY=e.clientY || event.screenY || event.pageY;
 eX=e.clientX || event.screenX || event.pageX;
  console.log(e.clientX);console.log(event.screenX );console.log(event.pageX);
 if( eY < 0 && eX>50) {
       $('#cart-reminder').removeClass('off-screen').addClass('center-over'); 
    $('#grey-out').removeClass('off-screen').addClass('grey-out-on');
   
      }
   }

$(document).on('mouseleave', leaveFromTop);
```

ClientX alone works in the other browsers.When I log clientX, ScreenX and pageX in IE11 I get -1 for all three. In older versions of IE I get -1,-1,undefined. When the mouseleave triggers on the right or to the bottom of side of the screen the values are correct but anything to the left of top returns -1.

Comment: What about the other ~50 ways of closing the browser? Not everyone uses a mouse.

Comment: Well the concern isn't so much that every user sees the ad. My goal is to actually show it to less users (only to people changing tabs or gong to the address bar). It already works if you simply have if( eY < 0). The part that breaks in IE is the eX>50, since the X values return -1 instead of the actual x-position of the mouse.

Comment: Track the movement before it goes out and see what the value was previously.

Comment: That's good thinking. I was thinking along those lines as well, that's what I'll likely do. I posted this question mostly because I couldn't find much on the subject and was wondering why IE reports the x value differently than the other browsers, figured others could benefit from the more broad part of the question.